# Issue with CSS3 Animation on multiple element

Tags: css, css-transitions

I need to animate two elements on a "hover" action of parent element.

**JS fiddle is: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/velmurugansp/qrmWA/)**

I have included the same code here:

here is my **HTML** code:

```
<div class="dealList"><a href="#" title="View Deal" class="viewDeal"><span>&nbsp;</span>View</a></div>
```

And **CSS3** is

```
-webkit-animation-name: expand;-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;    -moz-animation-name: expand;     -moz-animation-duration: 1s;     -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;}.dealList .viewDeal span{    display: inline-block;    width: 14px;    height: 14px;    background: url(../images/star_view.png) no-repeat;    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;}.dealList .viewDeal:hover span{    -webkit-animation-name: rotate;     -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;    -moz-animation-name: rotate;    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;}@-webkit-keyframes rotate {    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}}@-moz-keyframes rotate {    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}}@-webkit-keyframes expand {    from {width: 14px;}    to {width: 80px;}}@-moz-keyframes expand {    from {width: 14px;}    to {width: 80px;}}
```

I need the star to rotate and the "view" should come. and once the width reaches the maximum limit, it should stay with that and the star should stop rotating.

Please help me out to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

change your display property to `inline-block`.

```
.dealList .viewDeal{
    display: inline-block; 
    ...
```

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qrmWA/1/

Comment: Actually "view" text should be visible once it appears. But here width sets to '0' once it reaches the maximum limit. Hope u can get my point